# return value of this, further explanation

Tags: java, this

I wrote the following code:

```
class samplethis {

    int a = 6;
    int b = 7;
    String c = "i am";

    public void sample() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}

public class thiss {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        samplethis cal = new samplethis();
        cal.sample();// return samplethis@1718c21
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why it returns `samplethis@1718c21`?

Answer (score 7):

Your code doesn't *return* anything - it *prints* the result of calling `this.toString()`.

Unless you've overridden `Object.toString()`, you get the [default implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Having the hash code there makes it easier to spot *probably equal* references to the same object. If you write:

```
Foo foo1 = getFooFromSomewhere();
Foo foo2 = getFooFromSomewhere();
System.out.println("foo1 = " + foo1);
System.out.println("foo2 = " + foo2);
```

and the results are the same, then `foo1` and `foo2` probably refer to the same object. It's not guaranteed, but it's at least a good indicator - and this string form is really *only* useful for diagnostics anyway.

If you want to make your code print something more useful, you need to override `toString`, e.g. (in `samplethis`)

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("samplethis {a=%d; b=%d; c=%s}", a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: thanks, really helpful, i got your point, so the default toString() method is pretty useful when i want to know which object that "this" refers to